# coursework connecting to database

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to connect a database to my program using MySQL workbench. I am trying to get this connection between a webserver using phpMyAdmin and having no luck connecting to it. Giving me the following error every time I try to do this. [image: 1]

This is the connection data I'm using

[image: This is the current data I have entered for my connection.]

Comment: Well, did you 1: Make sure the server is running? 2: Ensure your computer that's running MySQL workbench can reach the server (try `ping`ing it) 3: Double check that you're connecting to the right server (maybe try replacing the name with its IP)

Comment: Does your hosting provider allow direct remote access in the first place? If yes, have you configured your mysql to be accessible remotely?

Comment: Is there a way I can check this? Could an index file be used for this?